# MVC3 AJAX Cascading DropDownLists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get cascading drop down lists to work for my asp.net mvc3 application.  I have a popup box and I would like to display 2 dropdownlists, the 2nd being populated based on what is selected in the first.  Each time I run the application the controller method returns the correct list of values, but instead of hitting the success part of the ajax call I hit the error part.  I have done lots of research and followed several examples I have found but something is still not quite right, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Further inspection using firebug shows an error 500 internal server error which states: Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.GameEdition

I have the following jQuery / AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#PlatformDropDownList").change(function () {
        var gameId = '@Model.GameID';
        var platformId = $(this).val();
        // and send it as AJAX request to the newly created action 
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Editions")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { gameId: gameId, platformId: platformId },
            cache: 'false',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#EditionDropDownList').empty();
                // when the AJAX succeeds refresh the ddl container with 
                // the partial HTML returned by the PopulatePurchaseGameLists controller action 
                $.each(result, function (result) {
                    $('#EditionDropDownList').append(
                        $('<option/>')
                            .attr('value', this.EditionID)
                            .text(this.EditionName)
                    );

                });
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('An Error has occurred');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my controller method:

```
  public JsonResult Editions(Guid platformId, Guid gameId)
  {
     //IEnumerable<GameEdition> editions = GameQuery.GetGameEditionsByGameAndGamePlatform(gameId, platformId);
     var editions = ugdb.Games.Find(gameId).GameEditions.Where(e => e.PlatformID == platformId).ToArray<GameEdition>();

     return Json(editions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Here is my web form html:

```
<div id="PurchaseGame">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct the errors and try again.")
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend></legend>
            <p>Select the platform you would like to purchase the game for and the version of the game you would like to purchase.</p>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlatformID, "Game Platform")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PlatformID, new SelectList(Model.Platforms, "GamePlatformID", "GamePlatformName"), new { id = "PlatformDropDownList", name="PlatformDropDownList" })
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EditionID, "Game Edition")
            </div>
            <div id="EditionDropDownListContainer">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EditionID, new SelectList(Model.Editions, "EditionID", "EditionName"), new { id = "EditionDropDownList", name = "EditionDropDownList" })
            </div>

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GameID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Platforms)

            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Purchase Game" />
                <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Cancel" />
            </p>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot send JSON encoded requests using the GET verb. So replace `type: 'GET'` with `type: 'POST'` and it will work. Also since you have specified a JSON request you must, well, send a JSON request which is achieved with the `JSON.stringify` function: `data: JSON.stringify({ gameId: gameId, platformId: platformId }),`. But since you only have 2 values I think that using GET would be easier. So my recommendation is to remove the `contentType: 'application/json'` parameter and have your AJAX request look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Editions")',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { gameId: gameId, platformId: platformId },
    cache: 'false',
    success: function (result) {
        $('#EditionDropDownList').empty();
        // when the AJAX succeeds refresh the ddl container with 
        // the partial HTML returned by the PopulatePurchaseGameLists controller action 
        if(result.length > 0)
        {
            $.each(result, function (result) {
                $('#EditionDropDownList').append(
                    $('<option/>')
                         .attr('value', this.EditionID)
                         .text(this.EditionName)
                );
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#EditionDropDownList').append(
                $('<option/>')
                    .attr('value', "")
                    .text("No edition found for this game")
            );
        }

    },
    error: function () {
        alert('An Error has occured');
    }
});
```

Also in the `DropDownListFor` helper in your Razor markup I notice the following:

```
onchange = "Model.PlatformID = this.value;"
```

All I can say is that this doesn't do what you might think it does.

---

UPDATE:

It seems that you are getting a circular object reference error because you are passing your `editions` domain model to the Json method. Circular reference object hierarchies cannot be JSON serialized. Besides you don't need to waste the bandwidth by sending all the crap contained in this editions to the client. All your client needs is a collection of ids and names. So simply use view models:

```
public ActionResult Editions(Guid platformId, Guid gameId)
{
    var editions = ugdb
        .Games
        .Find(gameId)
        .GameEditions
        .Where(e => e.PlatformID == platformId)
        .ToArray<GameEdition>()
        .Select(x => new 
        {
            EditionID = x.EditionID,
            EditionName = x.EditionName
        })
        .ToArray();

    return Json(editions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.  I have implemented your suggestion but am still ending up in the error section of the javascript rather than the success section.  I also tried doing the JSON.stringify and changing the controller method and type to 'POST' but get the same error result.  Also I removed the onchange as your right it wasn't doing what I thought it was.  I have edited my post with the updated code.

Comment: Is the controller action being invoked? Does it run without an exception? What do you see in FireBug? What does the server send in response to the AJAX request?

Comment: The controller action is being invoked successfully without exception and the editions variable has the correct values in it.  I did notice that I am getting an internal server 500 error saying something about a circular reference.  I updated my post to include this error message in more detail.  I researched it a bit and from what I understand this is usually caused by the json return not being formatted or read correctly, but I am unsure how to fix it.  The editions variable does point to a list of GameEdition entity objects so maybe it doesn't know how to handle that correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. You cannot JSON serialize circular object reference hierarchies. You will have to use view models. Get rid of this editions variable and define a view model which doesn't contain circular references and then pass an instance of this view model to the Json method that you are returning. You will have to include only the information that your consumer needs, not your entire domain model. And you only need a collection of a model that contains the id and the name. I have updated my post to show you an example.